# How to bind rows from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, simulation, lapply

I have a list of dataframes where each have 700 rows and 11 columns. I would like to create a big dataframe containing all 2100 rows and 11 columns.

This works, but is there a better way if I have 100 dataframes in the list?

```
list = [list1, list2, list3]
combineddf <- rbind(list[[1]], list[[2]], list[[3]])
```

Comment: In base, `do.call(list, rbind)`. Or `dplyr::bind_rows(list)`, or `data.table::rbindlist(list)`.

Comment: In general, `do.call(list, foo)` is equivalent to `foo(list[[1]], list[[2]], list[[3]], ...)`. And if the `list` has names, they will be interpreted as argument names for `foo()`.